# Conditional and Message Button

Tags: vb.net

I have

```
if x<-1 and x>1 Then

[if that condition is not met, I want a Message saying "Hey, you need a number
between -1 and 1.]

End if
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This condition will never satisfy.

Comment: @Fabio actually the condition to display the message would be `x < -1 OrElse x > 1`

Comment: @Katerine Arias Please explain more specifically what you are having problem with so we can help.

Comment: @bugs - the number could be a non-integer of course.

Comment: @DavidWilson That seems plausible. With a bit of luck the OP will reply however like many others they seem to have created an account, asked an unclear question and then disappeared.  I've flagged as unclear for now.

Comment: @Bugs Maybe. Guessing by her name though, English isn't her primary language, so I'm guessing that's why the question isn't quite clear.

Comment: @DavidWilson very much the issue with a lot of questions which yes is slightly unfair as I do try to help those that have at least tried. However this question shows very little and doesn't provide much for SO. Remove the `I have a problem` and the `please heelp!!` and you're left with very little. To me it just shows lack of effort, regardless of language.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a message box to pop up when x is outside your range then try this:-

```
If x < -1 OrElse x > 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Hey, you need a number in the range of -1 and 1")
End If
```